# How can I use a `lambda-expression` in the `select` tokens of a `query-expression` in C#

Tags: c#, linq, select, lambda, capture

I want use a `lambda-expression` in the `select` tokens. For a example simplified is below:

```
  // Example-0; It is NOT compilable.
  var xs = from v in Enumerable.Range( 0, 4 ) select w => w;
```

But, the example cannot compile. ( I'm using C#-7.0/.net Framework 4.7.2 )

> error CS1942: An expression type in `select' clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to`Select'

I tried the other sililar pattern in the below:

```
  // Example-1; It can compile.
  Func< int, int > f = w => w;
  var xs = from v in Enumerable.Range( 0, 4 ) select ( v, f );
```

But, the Example-1 is messy and it cannot capture a value in the `select` tokens.

```
  // Example-2; It is NOT compilable.
  var xs = from v in Enumerable.Range( 0, 4 ) select w => w + v;
```

How could I code it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use such syntax to select a `Func<int, int>`:

```
var xs = from v in Enumerable.Range(0, 4) select new Func<int, int>(x => x + v);
```

I'm not sure about the real scenario which you are going to use it, but for example you can call those funcs this way:

```
xs.ToList().ForEach(x => MessageBox.Show(x(1).ToString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose whether you want to use method syntax or query syntax. Mixing them makes them fairly unreadable, difficult to grasp, difficult to test and difficult to maintain.

When using method syntax your queries would be easy:

```
var result = Enumerable.Range( 0, 4 ); // no select needed
```

Assuming you simplified your problem:

```
Func<int, int> f = x => 4*x*x - 2*x +8;
var result = Enumerable.Range(0,4).Select(x => f(x));
```

In words: Calculate F(x) from every x in the collection of the the four integer values starting from 0.

or:

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(0,4).Select(i => 4*i*i - 2*i + 8;
```

Comment: Maybe the question is a bit ambiguous, but it seems the OP wants to select funcs as result. The way that you select, it's not selecting funcs, it's selecting result of a func. For example, you cannot get the first element of the result, without executing the the func.